# Constraint to avoid combination of foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, constraints, postgresql-9.3

I've here a problem that I couldn't find a proper solution on my researches, maybe it's because I couldn't find out the exact terms to search for it, so if this is a duplicate I will delete it.

My problem is I want to know if it is possible to avoid a combination of data between two fields. I will show the structure and the kind of data I want to avoid. It will be easier to understand.

```
Table_A                         Table_B
------------------------        -------------------------------               
id integer (PK)                 id integer (PK) 
description varchar(50)         title varchar(50)
                                id1_fromA  (FK A->id)
                                id2_fromA  (FK A->id)
```

I'm trying to validate the following data on table `Table_B` (combination is between id1_fromA and id2_fromA)

```
id   title          id1_fromA  id2_fromA  
1    Some Title         1         2 --It will be permmited
2    Some other         1         2 --It is a duplicate NOT ALLOWED
3    One more           1         1 --It is equals NOT ALLOWED
4    Another            2         1 --It is same as registry id 1 so NOT ALLOWED
5    Sample data        3         2 --It is ok
```

With above data I can easily solve the problem for registry `ID=2` with

```
ALTER TABLE table_B ADD CONSTRAINT UK_TO_A_FKS UNIQUE (id1_fromA, id2_fromA);
```

And the problem for registry `ID=3` with

```
ALTER TABLE table_B ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_TO_A_FKS CHECK (id1_fromA != id2_fromA);
```

My Problem is with the registry `ID=4` I want to avoid such duplicate of combination as `1,2`=`2,1`. Is it possible to do it with a `CONSTRAINT` or an `INDEX` or an `UNIQUE` or I will need to create a trigger or a procedure to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a unique constraint, but you can do this with a unique *index*.

```
create unique index UK_TO_A_FKS 
   on table_b (least(id1_froma, id2_froma), greatest(id1_froma, id2_froma));
```