# Postgres "reverse" foreign key contraint

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraints

I am not sure the best way to describe this, so please bear with me.

I have a database related to plant and animals species that occur in Oklahoma. One table therein, acctax (accepted taxonomy), contains the accepted name of a given taxon. Another table, syntax (synonym taxonomy), contains the synonyms of a taxon (one to many relationship).

We have devised a code (called acode), based on a taxon's scientific binomial, to uniquely identify each. For instance, the American bison (*Bison bison*) has the unique code M-BIBI. In the acctax table, this is the primary key. If another taxon had a similar binomial (for instance, a mammal whose generic and specific name both started with Bi, we would merely add a sequential number after it, e.g. M-BIBI2--fortunately, in this instance, this is only hypothetical, no such case exists).

The syntax table relates to the acctax table via this code. However, we also assign each synonym a unique identifier using the same convention (called the scode). This serves as the primary key in in the syntax table.

Where it becomes ridiculously tedious is the taxonomy occasionally changes. An accepted name can become a synonym and a synonym can become an accepted name. As a result, I absolutely need to ensure that no newly assigned "acode" is already in use as an "scode" in the syntax table and that no newly assigned "scode" is not already in use as an "acode" in the acctax table.

To partially solve this, I have created a view that unions the acode and scode from the acctax and syntax tables, respectively. Prior to adding new records, I can query the view to see if it a newly created code is already in use. However, I would prefer to have a constraint that will only allow the insert of a new acode or scode in the acctax and syntax tables, respectively, if that code does **not** already exist in the view I created.

Hopefully, this makes sense. I realize it is long and convoluted.

Comment: It is well explained but it would be better if you added your tables schema (at least the important part of then) and some sample data explaining your case. Right now I'm in doubt if what I understand will fit to your problem. Take a look at this question that I did some time ago, it is what I think I did understand :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647360/constraint-to-avoid-combination-of-foreign-keys

Comment: Why do you need the `acode` and `scode`. Why not just use the taxonomy names?

Comment: Excellent question. Unfortunately, taxonomy is very messy and, though a taxonomic name should be unique, there are instances in which it is not--such as when the same scientific binomial has different authors. This would require a concatenation with the scientific authorship field.